# How to add a Facebook share button for a different id post from a playlist

Tags: wordpress, joomla, playlist

I am new on programming.I need a playlist like 9gag.tv 
This one
http://9gag.tv/p/aKWL1D/marvel-vs-dc-animation-film?ref=hl
I am working on Wordpress

What do you suggest? Is there a possibility to find any plugin?
What about if there is a possibility for modules like that  in Joomla...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is brand new module for that
http://www.joomlaxtc.com/joomla-extensions/youtube-playlist-wall

it cost $19,but it looks same as you descirbe. Looka at the [demo](http://demo.joomlaxtc.com/extensions3/index.php/ytc-demo-7)